# Unable to install WildFly/ JBoss Server in Eclipse IDE Photon Release Candidate 3 (4.8.0RC3)

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, wildfly, wildfly-8

I was **trying to install WildFly/JBoss Server in Eclipse IDE Photon Release Candidate 3 (4.8.0RC3) but I'm getting an error**. I have attached the screenshot for the same.

Would somebody help me out here in this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem.

In Eclipse -> Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, search for "TM Terminal". Uninstall it, restart Eclipse and try to define a new server again. It will now install Wildfly, at least for me it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it really solved the problem for me as well.

Comment: Working, saved me from insanity after 2 day of searching,

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I was using Eclipse 2021-06 version and whatever I do I couldn't get the JBoss Community folder with different Wildfly servers to show.

I've downloaded the newest Eclipse (it was 2022-09 at this time) and everything was there after I installed the JBoss Tools in Eclipse Marketplace.